# Reverse triangle lookup from affected pixels?

Tags: opengl, mesh

Assume I have a 3D triangle mesh, and a OpenGL framebuffer to which I can render the mesh.

For each rendered pixel, I need to build a list of triangles that rendered to that pixel, even those that are occluded.

The only way I could think of doing this is to individually render each triangle from the mesh, then go through each pixel in the framebuffer to determine if it was affected by the triangle (using the depth buffer or a user-defined fragment shader output variable). I would then have to clear the framebuffer and do the same for the next triangle.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I considered, for each fragment in the fragment shader, writing out a triangle identifier,  but GLSL doesn't allow outputting a list of integers.

Comment: _Just out of curiosity:_ What's the bigger picture to this question?

Comment: How do you expect to do this quickly? Unless you limit yourself greatly this grows quite fast; Let's make a conservative sketch--for a 1024x768 resolution lets say you identify each triangle by 2-byte index into an array.  Each triangle may then require up to 1.5MB of storage. With even a conservative scene you're looking at hundreds to thousands of triangles--easily gigabytes of data to hold in some cases.

Comment: @StefanHanke, basically I need to be able to re-render a subset of my mesh. Specifically, given a fixed viewpoint, I locally modify my mesh and need to update the corresponding pixels (without having to re-render the whole mesh).

Comment: @RonWarholic I'm not sure I understand. Assuming each pixel is affected by at most 20 triangles (the mesh is nearly flat relative to the camera), then the required space will be 1024x768x20x2 = 30MB total (assuming like you did two bytes per triangle identifier).

Answer (score 1):

> For each rendered pixel, I need to build a list of triangles that rendered to that pixel, even those that are occluded.

You will not be able to do it for entire scene. There's no structure that allow you to associate "list" with every pixel.

You can get list of primitives that affected certain area using select buffer (see [`glRenderMode(GL_SELECT)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRenderMode.xml)).

You can get scene depth complexity using stencil buffer techniques.

If there are 8 triangles total, then you can get list of triangles that effected every pixel using stencil buffer (basically, assign unique (1 << n) stencil value to each triangle, and OR it with existing stencil buffer value for every stencil OP).

But to solve it in generic case, you'll need your own rasterizer and LOTS of memory to store per-pixel triangle lists. The problem is quite similar to multi-layered depth buffer, after all.

> Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Actually, yes, but it is not hardware accelerated and OpenGL has nothing to do it. Store all rasterized triangles in OCT-tree. Launch a "ray" through that OCT-tree for every pixel you want to test, and count triangles this ray hits. That's collision detection problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate the select buffer. Actually, multi-layered color/depth buffers would be ideal, since my goal is to modify a mesh locally and only re-render to a region of the framebuffer, specifically the region that is affected by the deformed section of mesh (and previously occluded triangles could become visible).

Comment: Perhaps a single layer is sufficient, very much like tile-based renderers work. Split the screen into `n*m` tiles, project all triangle's vertices to screen and build up a data structure holding all affecting triangles per tile.

Comment: @StefanHanke: I'd still recommend to use OCT-tree instead.

Comment: _/me currently thinking about the tradeoffs between oct trees and tiling_